# Is there a way to cache multiple http requests rxjs with shareReplay

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to cache requests which we get from multiple objects which can have the same url as array something like this

```
    const a = { urls: ['foo', 'bar'] };
    const b = { urls: ['bar', 'other'] };
```

I don't want to make a new request once I'm iterating through b urls if a url bar has been requested

I've tried this method which is not working for obvious reasons that logic is not complete

```
    private allUrls = [];  
    private allUrls$: Observable<{ "...someproperties"; url: string }> =  
        new Observable();
    private api$ = this.allUrls$.pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.allUrls$),
        shareReplay(1)
    );

    fetchRequest(urls: string[]) {
        urls.map((url) => {
            if (!this.allUrls.includes(url)) {
                this.allUrls$.pipe(mergeMap(() => this.cacheUrl(url)));
            }
        });

        return this.api$.pipe(
            map((response) => {
                return response.filter((r) => urls.includes(r.url));
        })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong you are searching solution like this. Please check my comments carefully.

```
export class App {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  // This is the chache
  private urlCache: Record<string, string[]> = {};
  onRequest(size: string) {
    // in your case you must return this observable from 
    // your function. Here we constructing url's which are
    // different only by their size parameter. We are doing 
    // this because need to test the implementation somehow ...
    of(`https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=${size}`)
      .pipe(
        concatMap((requestUrl: string) =>
          iif(
            () => typeof this.urlCache[requestUrl] !== 'undefined',
            of(this.urlCache[requestUrl]).pipe(
              tap((users) => {
                console.log(`This request url was cached. We are geting this response from cache.`, users);
              })
            ),
            this.http.get<{ first_name: string }[]>(requestUrl).pipe(
              map((users) => users.map((user) => user.first_name)),
              tap((users) => {
                this.urlCache[requestUrl] = users.slice();
                console.log(`This request url was not cached. We are geting this response from the server.`, users);
              })
            )
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((value) => {
        // This is the subscribed observer. 
        console.log(`This is the data which we get in subsbibed observer`, value);
      });
  }
}
```

Here you can see working stackblitz url.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eallsn?file=src/main.ts

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it wasn't exactly what I needed but it helped me a lot in doing it basically I used urlCache: Record<string, Oservable<interface>> = {};
urlCache[url] = this.onRequest(url);

and I made the onRequest return an Observable which pipelined shareReplay()

Comment: @Jango If the answer helped you may you accept it?